# Maximum call stack size exceeded for joi.string().base64()

Tags: javascript, node.js, joi

I am getting next error:

```
node_modules/joi/lib/types/string/index.js:464
            if (regex.test(value)) {
                      ^

RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at RegExp.test (<anonymous>)
```

for code:

```
 const res = validate({ body: request }, {
    body: joi.object({
    image: joi.string().base64() // image base64 size in near 4MB
```

How I can fix this limit error?

Comment: show the full stack and full example

Comment: the code is in infinite loop